# Making dynamic Link using mysql query but making php can Read it

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask a problem that might be quite simple. But I'm confused about where to find a solution.

I tried dynamically creating menu, by fetching the data with a mysql query, I managed to get the data together with the html format I wanted

```
    SELECT CONCAT("<ul>", dede, web, "</ul>") as persetujuan FROM
(SELECT  
 concat("<li><a href='#'>",permissionweb1.`Description`,"</a><ul>") as dede , GROUP_CONCAT("<li><a href='../",grup.FolderName,"'>", grup.Description, "</a></li>" SEPARATOR ' ') as web
FROM
  `permissionweb`
  INNER JOIN `employeewebpermission` ON (`permissionweb`.`ID` = `employeewebpermission`.`WebPermission`)
  INNER JOIN `employee` ON (`employeewebpermission`.`Employee` = `employee`.`ID`)
  INNER JOIN `permissionweb` `permissionweb1` ON (`permissionweb`.`ParentID` = `permissionweb1`.`ID`)
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT `employeewebpermission`.`WebPermission`, `permissionweb`.`Description`, `permissionweb`.`FolderName`
      FROM `employeewebpermission`
      INNER JOIN `permissionweb`   ON (`permissionweb`.`ID` = `employeewebpermission`.`WebPermission`)

) grup ON (grup.WebPermission = `permissionweb`.ID)
WHERE
  `employee`.`ID` = 1468
GROUP BY `permissionweb`.`ParentID`) PERMISSION
```

The result is like this per-row

```
 <ul><li><a href='#'>IT</a><ul><li><a href='../cpu'>Daftar CPU</a></li> <li><a href='../itstok'>Stok IT</a></li> <li><a href='../itstok'>Stok IT</a></li> <li><a href='../hardware'>Daftar Hardware</a></li> <li><a href='../cpu'>Daftar CPU</a></li> <li><a href='../cpu'>Daftar CPU</a></li> <li><a href='../itstok'>Stok IT</a></li> <li><a href='../hardware'>Daftar Hardware</a></li> <li><a href='../cpu'>Daftar CPU</a></li> <li><a href='../itstok'>Stok IT</a></li> <li><a href='../hardware'>Daftar Hardware</a></li> <li><a href='../hardware'>Daftar Hardware</a></li></ul>
```

and my job now is just to echo the php. But the problem is because the html format... i can't excecute the sql from php, like this image..

[image]

Iknow the problem is the concat of ul and li, what format should i do? yes i MUST using that query and doing echo and not making html.

Thank you..

Comment: You need to escape all `"` by adding \ before every `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape double quotes

```
SELECT CONCAT(\"<ul>\", dede, web, \"</ul>\") as persetujuan FROM
(SELECT  
 concat(\"<li><a href='#'>\",permissionweb1.`Description`,\"</a><ul>\") as dede , GROUP_CONCAT(\"<li><a href='../\",grup.FolderName,\"'>\", grup.Description, \"</a></li>\" SEPARATOR ' ') as web
FROM
  `permissionweb`
  INNER JOIN `employeewebpermission` ON (`permissionweb`.`ID` = `employeewebpermission`.`WebPermission`)
  INNER JOIN `employee` ON (`employeewebpermission`.`Employee` = `employee`.`ID`)
  INNER JOIN `permissionweb` `permissionweb1` ON (`permissionweb`.`ParentID` = `permissionweb1`.`ID`)
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT `employeewebpermission`.`WebPermission`, `permissionweb`.`Description`, `permissionweb`.`FolderName`
      FROM `employeewebpermission`
      INNER JOIN `permissionweb`   ON (`permissionweb`.`ID` = `employeewebpermission`.`WebPermission`)

) grup ON (grup.WebPermission = `permissionweb`.ID)
WHERE
  `employee`.`ID` = 1468
GROUP BY `permissionweb`.`ParentID`) PERMISSION
```

However I feel you should prepare the menu in PHP instead of MySQL